# Angular Dart - How can I make the attribute minlength to work with a dynamic value?

Tags: forms, validation, angular-dart

How can I make the attribute `minlength` to work with a dynamic value?

For example I have next code:

```
<input class="form-control"
       id="name"
       type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="model.name"
       #name="ngForm"
       required
       [minLength]="minLength"/>
{{name.errors}}
```

and `name.errors` is empty when text length is less than `minLength`.

I have also tried:

```
<input class="form-control"
       id="name"
       type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="model.name"
       #name="ngForm"
       required
       [minlength]="minLength"/>
```

and this:

```
<input class="form-control"
       id="name"
       type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="model.name"
       #name="ngForm"
       required
       minlength="{{minLength}}"/>
```

but I got next error:

```
ParseErrorLevel.FATAL: Can't bind to 'minlength' since it isn't a known native property or known directive. Please fix typo or add to directives list.
[minlength]="minLength"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are setting somewhat custom attribute, try `attr.` syntax

```
<input [attr.minlength]="minLength">
```

Comment: event the html attribute is set in the DOM, the validator is never triggered